# How to manage incompatible branches for an internal library

Tags: git, maven

We've got an internal utility library that we maintain for our applications that run in MRv1.  The project is built using maven, and Git is our source control system.  We've been following the usual master/develop/feature branching style up to this point.

The recent change has been the arrival of an MRv2 environment.  Our applications that are targeting MRv2 need a different set of dependencies.  After a bit of experimenting, I've now got a private branch that builds a new artifact that works.

(Clarification: MRv2 introduces new package names and incompatible interfaces.  The library artifacts we are building provide a consistent facade for the two different implementations behind them).

The riddle is how to continue library development for both the MRv1 and MRv2 artifacts.

Does anybody know of a documented convention that covers this situation at the branch level?  Or is it simply a truth that trying to manage this separation with branches is the Wrong Problem to have?

Comment: If I understand correctly... You have a utility library that many of your applications use. The utility library acts as a facade/adapter so it will work with both MRv1 and MRv2. The applications have no MRvX code. Do you intend to have separate branches of the utility library for MRv1 and MRv2? Or does one set of code handle both versions?

Comment: AsIs: the code in the two branches is very slightly different.  So I'm building two different versions of the code, not one version of the code two different ways.  Saying the same thing - two different artifactIds, rather than one artifactId with two different classifiers.